# How to create a session object in an application

Tags: android, session, android-webview

In my app i want to create a session for login and log out.

I dont have any idea how to work with session.
Anybody help me by giving some sample example.

Comment: why are you trying for a session object. Are you just trying to keep something in memory until the app closes?

Comment: bcz in my app i am opening own website. so for login and logout session is required.

Comment: So you are trying to using this with the web view. You might want to edit that question to include the information. It will get you more answers.

Comment: This is a very good example, this should help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1):

I think the session object should be a static object declared and initialized when your application starts running. I have met this problem and decided to put my session object in a utils class which contains mathods used by every activity in my app.

Here is a  short example:

1. create a class for utils which will contain session object, Session is the class by which you implement your session object. It can contain, for example, userId, userName, etc.:

   ```
   public class Utils {  
       public static Session mySessionObject = null;
   }
   ```
2. When login button is pushed initialize your session object:

   ```
   login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Utils.mySessionObject = new Session();
          //some extra initalization, for example setting userId
       }
   });
   ```

On logout you can destroy your session object.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067383/what-is-session-management-in-java) is a link telling more about sessions.

Comment: i want to start a session as soon as i login

Comment: if you login by clicking a button, initialize your session object when the button is clicked

Comment: Sure, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Session is not taking in my app why?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not taking in my app"?

Comment: for example if u write Button btnLogin; then asking for import button . but public static Session mySessionObject = null;
this is shoing err for Session ,, no imports are there

Comment: oh. Of course you must have a Session class adapted for your need and you should import it where neseccary.

Comment: but whats the benifit ?  bcz  in java predefined session is there

Comment: Honestly I'm not familiar with java predefined session, so I can't say the diffecence. But I've found a link which I think will help you. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Will u plz give me that link?

Comment: This is actually a link for asp.net but it is very helpfull: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Application-and-Session-Objects-in-ASP.NET/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to keep some data in memory during the life of your app, maybe you should consider using a singleton pattern. I use it this way.

```
public class Session {  

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GoogleAnalyticsTracker mGoogleAnalyticsTracker = null;

    private static Session sInstance               = null;

    private Session(Context pContext) {

        mGoogleAnalyticsTracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        mGoogleAnalyticsTracker.startNewSession(pContext.getString(R.string.google_analytics_web_property_id), 
                                                pContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_analytics_tracking_time_in_seconds),
                                                pContext.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static void init(Context pContext) {
        sInstance = new Session(pContext);
    }

    public static Session getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

I load the session during the splash screen. Keep in mind that with this solution you shouldn't keep big objects in memory.

```
Session.init(this);
```

For example I use it for the Google Analytics tracker initialization, development mode, etc