# Invalidate Session in JSP

Tags: java

I'm developing an application that user can log in in the system, and if another user tries to log in with the same id and password of the user that already logged, I need to invalidate the session of this user that already logged in and make him/her go back to the first page and make log in with the new user.

How can I develop this?

Comment: Why? What can't the user be logged in twice? What's the business problem being addressed here?

Comment: I'm developing a software to a company and them want so. I tried to say them to make different, but with them don't have conversation. Thank you by the opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to keep track of already logged-in users either in application scope/DB. For each user when you try to create a session, make sure no other session already exists. If exists by using [SessionListeners](http://www.coderanch.com/t/365859/Servlets/java/session-object-session-ID) you may need to do [session invalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29).

Comment: but how can I invalidate a session of another computer/person/browser?
Would have how make this by the server?

Comment: What do you mean by another computer/person/browser? Could you update question with a realistic scenario?

Comment: because I'm developing a software where each official of the company has a user in the system and the client wants that the system drop down the user that was logged in when to try to make login with the user that already logged in the system. Fo.r example: 
I will try to log in with a user, and the system detects that this user is already connected, then for me log in with this user, I have to invalidate his session, after that, I will log in normally.

Comment: If you are developing application, inside your application you will write logic for session management. So, for each user connection, your servlet container assings sessionID. From this sessionId you can findout the session on the container (server). Once you are able to identify the session you can invalidate. All this logic need to be coded by you inside the application you are developing.

Comment: Read these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835764/java-session-management and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067383/what-is-session-management-in-java

Comment: Ok, but I wanna invalidate the session from another browser in another computer. The server can get all sessions of all browsers?

Comment: Server is the one which maintains sessions for all connections (if your code contains session maintenance logic).

Comment: I found a method that gets all the sessions, but is deprecated and does not work, but I will save de session id in the database and when the user that was offline make something, the system will check and it will return to the log page. Nevertheless thank you by your time.